# How do you disable Icon grid snapping in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

Remember the "Snap to Grid" context menu option when you right clicked the desktop?  Well I was trying to arrange my icons in a certain way (like a brick stagger), and it was a no go.  They just kept snapping back in place.  That's when I noticed that particular option no longer exists in the context menu.  Is there a way to turn grid snapping off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i understand it right, what you want is:

- Right click desktop
- Go to view
- Untick 'Align icons to grid'